# Preciso de ajuda com esse select

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

**CAMPO1_FK**

```
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
103
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
108
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
434
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
4082
6394
6394
6394
6394
6394
6394
6394
6394
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
12315
```

**CAMPO2_FK**

```
196
190
138
136
136
134
133
130
129
128
125
124
121
119
118
190
189
188
187
186
185
182
182
181
174
173
164
163
162
160
159
157
149
149
149
148
146
145
144
143
142
140
140
130
129
128
125
124
190
189
188
182
182
181
178
173
168
168
168
163
162
161
153
147
145
144
143
136
134
130
120
190
189
188
184
182
173
168
163
162
161
154
136
135
127
126
190
189
188
184
182
156
136
134
198
197
190
189
188
184
182
163
162
136
134
```

O que eu preciso fazer é pegar o numero máximo do `CAMPO2_FK` referente a cada um dos números do `CAMPO1_FK`.

Por exemplo:

```
103-196 / 108-19 [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comando **MAX(CAMPO2_FK)** para pegar o maior valor, depois utilizar o **group by CAMPO1_FK** para filtrar esse valor para cada um dos campos que você precisa.

Ex:

```
SELECT MAX(CAMPO2_FK) from SuaTabela group by CAMPO1_FK
```

Esse select irá te listar o maior valor do **CAMPO2_FK**, referente a cada mudança que houver no **CAMPO1_FK**.

Espero ter lhe ajudado, caso ainda houver dúvidas, estou a disposição para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Isso mesmo !! 
Muito obrigado